How is $\emptyset$ both a complement of $U$ and $\subseteq U$
I am self-studying proofs with an intro to proofs book but have trouble understanding this. From my understanding, $\emptyset$ can be defined as the complement of the universal set ($U$). However, the book I am reading also mentions that $\emptyset$ is a subset of $U$. This statement seems contradictory to me. I am very new to any sort of set theory so I would really appreciate it if you guys could help clear things up.

Note that $\emptyset$ is the only subset of $U$ which is contained in its complement, which may explain your confusion? Many statements about the empty set are counterintuitive, but they make perfect mathematical sense: the empty set is vacuously contained in any other set.

I understand the apparent conflict: since the complement $A’$ of any set $A$ contains all and only those objects (relevant to some domain or ‘universal set’ $U$) that are not in $A$, one expects $A’$ to have elements that are not in $A$, and hence $A’$ can not be a subset of $A$.
So yes, in general, the complement $A’$ of a set $A$ is not a subset of that set … except when $A’$ is empty, i.e. when $A$ equals $U$. And that is because in that case there are no elements in $A’$, and therefore certainly no elements that are in $A’$ but not in $A$, and so in that case $A’$ is a subset of $A$.
Put differently: if $A$ is the universal set, then all objects that are not in $A$ becomes no objects at all. So it is an exceptional case that goes against your intuition.
